# deploying java web app to heroku: NoClassDefFoundError caused by ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, heroku, classnotfoundexception, noclassdeffounderror, javax.json

I followed this instruction:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java

to deploy a java web app to heroku.

The content of my Procfile is the following:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.michael.optimizer.Optimizer
```

(Optimizer is the name of my main class.)

Executing the command

```
mvn clean install
```

builds the project successfully.

But then executing the command

```
heroku local web
```

results in the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
5:33:48 PM web.1 |  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/json/Json
5:33:48 PM web.1 |  at com.michael.optimizer.api.JsonRequest.doJsonRequest(JsonRequest.java:29)
5:33:48 PM web.1 |      at         com.michael.optimizer.api.StationApi.doJsonRequest(StationApi.java:150)
5:33:48 PM web.1 |      at     com.michael.optimizer.api.StationApi.areaSearch(StationApi.java:73)
5:33:48 PM web.1 |      at com.michael.optimizer.Optimizer.main(Optimizer.java:23)
5:33:48 PM web.1 |  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.json.Json
5:33:48 PM web.1 |      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
5:33:48 PM web.1 |      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
5:33:48 PM web.1 |      at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
5:33:48 PM web.1 |      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
5:33:48 PM web.1 |      ... 4 more
```

What I don't understand is this: when I run the app locally, everything works fine. (And it's no surprise that it works fine because inside folder ~/.m2/repository/javax/javaee-web-api/7.0/javaee-web-api-7.0.jar there is the json package where it should be.)

Only when I try to deploy to heroku, class javax.json.Json is apparently not found.

What's wrong???

Comment: Can you verify that, after running `mvn clean install` locally, `javaee-web-api-7.0.jar` is present in your `target/dependency` directory?

Comment: @Malax: thank you very much for your answer and sorry for the late reply. I checked in folder target ... javaee-web-api-7.0.jar is NOT in that folder after running "mvn clean install" ... how can I change that?

Comment: Can you show the `<dependency>` section where you defined the JEE API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use [copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html),

```
mvn install dependency:copy-dependencies
```

This copy all the dependencies in **target/dependencies**.

If you want to exclude test scope dependencies,

```
mvn install dependency:copy-dependencies -DexcludeScope=test
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer ... I think this is the solution. Unfortunately, I cannot be sure right now because now - even when running the app locally (which was working without problems a couple of weeks ago) - I get another error message. For that other issue I asked a separate question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394742/failed-to-execute-goal-org-codehaus-mojoexec-maven-plugin1-5-0exec

Comment: I started a bounty of 500 for that other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394742/failed-to-execute-goal-org-codehaus-mojoexec-maven-plugin1-5-0exec)

Comment: @steady_progress added the answer. please check. I hope it helps.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer to the other question ... someone else gave the same answer before you so I had to give the bounty to him ... but I will give you additional 250 points for the answer provided above ... I still can't say for sure whether your answer above solves the problem because now I suddenly got a 404 error ... but I approved the answer now so you get 250 points for sure ... once I know the answer solves my problem, you will get 250 points more

Comment: I created a new question regarding the 404 error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61445520/getting-error-message-failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-stat

Comment: No need for the additional bounty. For the other question, it's not the same answer (Root cause explanation, javax.json-api is not required). I am glad it was helpful.