# getting error message "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Tags: netbeans, web-applications, localhost, payara

I have a simple MVC web application, which was running locally without problems 3 weeks ago.

When I now open the application in Netbeans and run it, everything seems to work fine as well. However, when I go to the browser (in my case google chrome) to look at the app's frontend (at http://localhost:8080/optimizer), I get the following error message:

```
HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
```

In Chrome's javascript console the following error message is given:

```
optimizer:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

"optimizer" is the name of the app. (What's the point of the "1" in "optimizer:1"? ... I don't get this either.)

The server (payara) is running:

[image]

I can also reach the server's admin page:

[image]

However, somehow the server cannot seem to find the application, although 3 weeks ago everything worked fine ... I just don't get it.
What's wrong? How can I fix this?

---

UPDATE:

Clicking on "List Deployed Applications" in Payara's Admin Console reveals that my app is not(!) deployed.

I tried to deploy it by clicking on "Deploy an Application" -> "Choose file".
I selected the jar-file "optimizer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar", selected Type "EJB Jar", then clicked on OK.

I got this error message:

```
Archive type of /private/var/folders/hh/hgq7wrjn5d51gy2tkbxkkbwh0000gn/T/optimizer-15075570634779987058.0-SNAPSHOT.jar was not recognized
```

How can I deploy my app?  And why did it work automatically before and now it doesn't work any more?

---

UPDATE 2:

A difference I realise compared to before (3 weeks ago) is that the browser doesn't open automatically any more when I run the app.
Furthermore, Google Chrome used to be the IDE'S default browser ... now there is just a grey globe and I can no longer choose Chrome as my browser:

[image]

---

UPDATE 3:

I just noticed there is an error message that appears when the server is started (it's in the middle of hundred of rows of log output so I didn't notice it at first):

[image]

---

UPDATE 4:

-> NetBeans IDE 11.2
-> Payara Server 5.193

Comment: What happens when you click "List Deployed Applications" from Payara's Admin Console? Is your application definitely deployed? If not, deploy it and try again...do you still get a 404?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ... Indeed the application does not seem to be deployed ... the list is empty .... so far I never had to do anything special to "deploy" the app ... I just needed to start the server and then press on "Run" (the green arrow) in the Netbeans IDE ... how can I deploy my application to the payara server ?

Comment: The deployment process varies slightly depending on the type of web project you created (maven vs. ant vs. gradle), and the application server being used. But if you ensure that Payara is not already running, then select your web application node from the _Projects_ panel, right click and select _Run_ from the context menu you should be fine now. (Why you need to redeploy is another story though.)

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Why would I want to make sure the server is NOT running?????

Comment: It's not a big deal, but if there was a server glitch for some reason - and that looks like that may have been the case for you - stopping/restarting the server may help, and certainly can't hurt. But you can just _Run_ if you wish.

Comment: I stopped and restarted the server several times .. I also redownloaded the server ... nothing worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212574/discussion-between-skomisa-and-steady-progress).

Comment: the problem seems to be that the connection between Netbeans IDE and the server seems to be broken, i.e. when I run the app in NetBeans, it does not get deployed to the server any more

Comment: Please click the chat link above if you want to pursue this...

Comment: Can you add the code base as well ?

Comment: I can't share the whole code base but I will try to provide a mini app ... the Payara server version is: Payara Server 5.193
The Netbeans Version is: NetBeans IDE 11.2

Comment: will try to provide a mini app within the next 24 hours

Comment: Please share the project. I will definitely solve your problem. I know where can be the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I now found out how to run the app locally without problems: by creating a .war file instead of a .jar file - now I can run the app again without problems.

Comment: @Code_Mode: I would like to give the bounty (for the other question) to you and Anish B. because you two put in the most effort ... is there a way of splitting the bounty or to transfer points (so I could give the bounty to one of you and that person would then transfer half of it to the other)?

Comment: @Anish B: I would like to give the bounty (for the other question) to you and Code_Mode because you two put in the most effort ... is there a way of splitting the bounty or to transfer points (so I could give the bounty to one of you and that person would then transfer half of it to the other)?

Comment: Thanks :). No that thing is not there. You can offer me the bounty there.

Comment: @steady_progress You can not split the bounty. Offer a bounty to an answer that solved your question or helped you in the right direction to solve your problem and that might be helpful to future readers as well. Thanks. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users

Comment: ok, I awarded the bounty to Michael because his answer showed me that the problem is not about the pom.xml file but about the server. This helped me to figure out myself that the server had a problem with the file format (,jar).

Answer (score 1):

Error clearly shows, server is not able to recognize archive type of jar,

> Archive type of
> /private/var/folders/hh/hgq7wrjn5d51gy2tkbxkkbwh0000gn/T/optimizer-15075570634779987058.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
> was not recognized

From [payara blog](https://blog.payara.fish/deploy-applications-using-payara-server-admin-console),

> If you set “Location” by “Packaged File to Be Uploaded to the Server”,
> the **suitable type would be selected**.

So, the suitable type would be selected automatically.

Also, `optimizer-15075570634779987058.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` is not an original jar `optimizer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

It seems that issue is with the path of an archive, from [thread](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/22739)

> Code in uploadFrame.jsf:
>
> `<sun:form id="form">`
>
> I probe to change it to:
>
> `<sun:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">`
>
> in uploadFrame.jsf into console-common.jar file. And it works.

You can try with changing `uploadFrame.jsf` into `console-common.jar` file.
(Not sure if chrome takes care of this, as it was working for you with chrome).

You may also want to try manual deployment,

```
install-directory/bin/asadmin deploy PATH_TO_ARCHIEVE/optimizer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: so where is this uploadFrame.jsf file?